# Why do I need to adjust after convert point?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

My scene is setup scene > world: `sknode` > camera: `sknode` > ship: `SKSpriteNode`

I want the ship to point to the location of the touch:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

  let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)
  let location      = cameraNode.convertPoint(touchLocation, toNode: world)


  moveCameraNode(CGPointsToVector(location, b: cameraNode.position))

  let shipTouchPosition = scene?.convertPoint(touchLocation, fromNode: world)
  let shipPosition      = scene?.convertPoint(ship.position, fromNode: world)

  let angle = atan2(shipTouchPosition!.y - shipPosition!.y, shipTouchPosition!.x - shipPosition!.x)

  let magicNumber = CGFloat(M_PI_2) 
  ship.runAction(SKAction.rotateToAngle(angle - magicNumber, duration: 0.1, shortestUnitArc: true))
}

override func didFinishUpdate() {
  centerOnNode(cameraNode)
}

func centerOnNode(node: SKNode) {
  let cameraPositionInScene = node.scene?.convertPoint(node.position, fromNode: node.parent!)
  node.parent!.position = CGPointsSubtract(node.parent!.position, b: cameraPositionInScene!)
}
```

So, it now works ok but I'm not sure why I need the `magicNumber.`

EDIT: Thanks to @mundi for catching a stupid error on my part which was obscuring my real question of what I'm doing wrong with convertPoint that I have to adjust it afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angles are calculated in radians. 360 degrees are 2 times the constant PI, or `2 * M_PI`. In SpriteKit, angle calculations start from center right (equivalent to 3 o'clock), corresponding to 90 degrees or one half PI, `M_PI_2`.

`80` read as radians evaluates to `1.46018` which is very close to `M_PI_2` or `1.57079`. This is why this number appears to "magically" fix this discrepancy, even though it is slightly off. The true "magic" number is `CGFloat(M_PI_2)`.

Comment: Thanks, I misremembered and thought `zRotation` and `atan2` were in degrees. Which is why when I tried 90 at first and it didn't work but 80, which is pretty close, was working I thought it was a "magic number." But my real question is why I need to adjust at all.

Comment: Right. I think the real question is answered as well.